# Is there an alternative to locking a table while updating a nested set in a multi-tenant database?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am working on a multi-tenant application using a single database. A few things (categories) will allow nesting and I had started out with a parent-child in mind before examining the nested sets methodology.

My primary concern with nested sets is the (apparent) need to lock the table when adding or removing an item from the tree. In a multi-tenant scenario, one user's category modifications would have severe performance implications on every other user on the system.

Is there an alternative means of insuring that the affected rows are not accessed? All rows would be identified by a common tenant_id.

Thank you in advance for any advice you can provide.

Comment: How many rows do the updates affect? Can you post the statement/procedure you use?

Comment: You have to deal with concurrency. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074946/do-table-locks-scale-would-row-locks-be-more-efficient-for-nested-sets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are modifying a row that row will be locked - there is no way around it. But my guess is that you meant preventing locking the whole table when modifying some rows.
To prevent this use InnoDB engine instead of MyIsam. MyIsam locks the whole table when making a change to any rows, while InnoDB doesn't.

See: "To achieve a very high lock speed, MySQL uses table locking (instead of page, row, or column locking) for all storage engines except InnoDB, BDB, and NDBCLUSTER." http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-locking.html

Comment: Thank you Zoltan. I had seen a few nested set examples that suggest a LOCK TABLE call before the operation to increment the lft and rgt values. It now seems that I could just tell the DB to update those values, then add the new node, and all would be well. The cascade may take a moment, though. Will test further but the info about InnoDB's locking scheme is great as I was using InnoDB for Foreign Keys anyways.